# unable to use the dataset in format .xlsb in Vertex AI for Time Series Forecasting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to import the data in Vertex AI . The Dataset is in .xlsb Format it requires me to convert them into .csv Files but during conversion it erases a a lot of data. Also when I try to seperately load the data ,In The BigQuery it cannot correctly identify the column names.
Please Help me I am stuck.[[Actual Image of Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci8Dm.png)][What is seen in BigQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4r4t.png)]

I have tried converting them into .csv and .xls format but still I am getting same results either the dataset loaded is incorrect or the BigQuery is unable to read it.